# python linear regression predict by date

Tags: python, date, pandas, linear-regression

I want to predict a value at a date in the future with simple linear regression, but I can't due to the date format.

This is the dataframe I have:

```
data_df = 
date          value
2016-01-15    1555
2016-01-16    1678
2016-01-17    1789
...  

y = np.asarray(data_df['value'])
X = data_df[['date']]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split             
(X,y,train_size=.7,random_state=42)

model = LinearRegression() #create linear regression object
model.fit(X_train, y_train) #train model on train data
model.score(X_train, y_train) #check score

print (‘Coefficient: \n’, model.coef_)
print (‘Intercept: \n’, model.intercept_) 
coefs = zip(model.coef_, X.columns)
model.__dict__
print "sl = %.1f + " % model.intercept_ + \
     " + ".join("%.1f %s" % coef for coef in coefs) #linear model
```

I tried to convert the date unsuccessfully

```
data_df['conv_date'] = data_df.date.apply(lambda x: x.toordinal())

data_df['conv_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_df.date, format="%Y-%M-%D")
```

Comment: might want to look into ARMA or ARIMA models for time series data

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Linear regression doesn't work on date data. Therefore we need to convert it into numerical value.The following code will convert the date into numerical value:

```
import datetime as dt
data_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_df['Date'])
data_df['Date']=data_df['Date'].map(dt.datetime.toordinal)
```

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't work - I get this error message TypeError: descriptor 'toordinal' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'

Comment: could i do this? data_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_df['date'],format='%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: Hi jeangelj, please add this line: import datetime as dt                        data_df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_df['Date']) data_df['Date']=data_df['Date'].map(dt.datetime.toordinal)

Comment: Please share the code snippet to convert it back to original value, this is because once I have converted date to numerical and predicted the numerical date value I want to convert it back to original format.

Answer (score 6):

convert:

1) date to dataframe index

```
df = df.set_index('date', append=False)
```

2) convert datetime object to float64 object

```
df = df.index.to_julian_date()
```

run the regression with date being the independent variable.

Answer (score 2):

Liner regression works on numerical data. Datetime type is not appropriate for this case. You should remove that column after separating it to three separate columns (year, month and day).

Answer (score 1):

When using

```
dt.datetime.toordinal
```

be careful that it only converts dates values and does not take into account minutes, seconds etc..  For a complete answer on generating ordinals from full datetime objects you can use something like:

```
df['Datetime column'].apply(lambda x: time.mktime(x.timetuple()))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is really important to differentiate the data types that you want to use for regression/classification.

When you are using time series, that is another case but if you want to use time data as a numerical data type as your input, then you should transform your data type from datetime  to float (if your `data_df['conv_date]` is a datetime object, if not then you should first transform it by using; `data_df['conv_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_df.date, format="%Y-%M-%D")` )

I agree with Thomas Vetterli's answer. It is useful to be careful what kind of time data you are using.

If you are only using year and month data then `dt.datetime.toordinal` would be enough to use;

```
>>import datetime
>>data_df['conv_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_df.date, format="%Y-%M-%D")
>>data_df['conv_date'] = data_df['conv_date'].map(datetime.datetime.toordinal)
737577
```

But if you want to use also the hour, minute and second information then `time.mktime()` suits better;

```
>>import time
>>data_df['conv_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_df.date, format="%Y-%M-%D")
>>data_df['conv_date'] = data_df['conv_date'].apply(lambda  var: time.mktime(var.timetuple()))
1591016041.0
```

Also 1591016044.0 is another exemplary output from my data, it varies with changes in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I'm diving into the different options given here and I just wanted to summarize them. It takes time to write a full answer but this is what I've researched.

### Examples reference

I took the same date with different data types following the requirements of each method. Maybe I'm missing other options.

```py
t = pd.Timestamp('2021-09-03 00:00:00')    
   # Timestamp('2021-09-03 00:00:00')   pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp
t2 = dtt.date(2021, 9, 3)          
   #  datetime.date(2021, 9, 3)     datetime.date
```

### Pandas methods

- [pandas.to_numeric](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html)

```py
pandas.to_numeric(arg, errors='raise', downcast=None)
# argscalar, list, tuple, 1-d array, or Series
```

###### Example

```py
st3 = pd.to_numeric(df_example.index, downcast='integer')
st3[0]  
1630627200000000000
```

### Python/Pandas with the same outcome

- [pandas.Timestamp.toordinal](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.toordinal.html)
- [Python-date.toordinal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.toordinal)

  Note: The Proleptic Gregorian ordinal gives the number of days elapsed from the date 01/Jan/0001. And here ordinal is called Proleptic since the Gregorian calendar itself is followed from October 1582.Aug 23, 2021.

```py
# I checked it out and I found a 215 days difference
hoy = dtt.date.today()   # datetime.date(2022, 8, 3)
hoy.toordinal()  # 738370   - (365 * 2022)  =  340
hoy.timetuple()  # tm_yday=215  ---> 340 - 215 = 125
```

###### Example

```py
t2.toordinal()
    738036
pd.Timestamp.toordinal(a) 
    738036
```

### Python methods

- [Python-datetime-module-datime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

  - [Python-time.mktime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.mktime)
  - [Python-datetime.date.timetuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.timetuple)

###### Example

```py
time.mktime(t2.timetuple())     
1630638000.0
```