# how do i fit a datetime column in linear regression even i have changed the column into datetime type?

Tags: python, pandas

datetime             datetime64[ns]-----earlier it was in object and later i converted it into datetime format

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'

Comment: I guess there is no such structure. You should use something like [Label Encoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) etc.

Comment: This can be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40217369/python-linear-regression-predict-by-date

Comment: `Timestamp` is just int64 underneath. You can convert it to Unix time with `df['date'].astype(np.int64)`. The returned numbers are in nanoseconds since Jan 1, 1970.