# how to use Date in string in LinearRegression model

Tags: python, linear-regression, sklearn-pandas, mlmodel

i want to use date like 8/12/2004 in LinearRegression model and convert all of the dataset to range like(0.2008)***strong text*** in order to sort date

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python linear regression predict by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40217369/python-linear-regression-predict-by-date)